# angular.js:12520 ReferenceError: ngTableParams is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, syntax-error, ngtable

please some help i tried all ways to make my controller but i got all the time errors : when its not "NgTableParams is not defined" its "$http.get" is not defined" please some help , i already watched all tutos and all questions here i could not resolve that.
Angular version : 1.4.8

```
(function() {
  "use strict";

  angular.module('timeShareApp')

  .controller("homeController", homeController);


  function homeController($http, $filter, NgTableParams) {
       var  home = this;
       home.users = []; //declare an empty array
       $http.get("/api/users/").success(function(response){ 
       home.users = response;  
       });

  console.log('users '+ home.users);

  home.userstable = new ngTableParams({
                page: 1,
                count: 10
            }, {
                total: home.users.length, 
                getData: function ($defer, params) {
                   home.data = home.users.slice((params.page() - 1) *               params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
                    $defer.resolve($scope.data);
                }
            });




 };
homeController.$inject = ["$http", "$scope" ,"NgTableParams"];


})();
```

and my app declare (app.js that works for all others controllers ) :

```
'use strict';

    angular.module('timeShareApp', ['ngRoute','ngAnimate', 'ngTable', "ngResource", 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngFileUpload', 'smoothScroll', 'countTo', 'filtreAccount', 'mp.datePicker']);
```

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: It's "new NgTableParams(...)", with a capital N.

Comment: @evsheino is spot on, earlier versions of ngTable had it starting with a lower case 'n', but in current versions, it's `NgTableParams `.

Comment: Hi , Really thank you so much for your help i really apreaciate it , i edited my files multiple times switched tutorials lol 

Thank you 

One of the most negatif point of JS World is versions changes.